# default text in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I don't know if this has a special name for it, but is there a nice easy way to set default text in an input field which disappears on focus and reappears on blur if the textbox is empty?

Comment: The name is placeholder. It's now officially part to the HTML(5) spec so all modern browsers support it as inline HTML. See my answer below for an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the word is **[WATERMARK](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/watermark)**

1. http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Watermark
2. http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/
3. http://cysemic.com/2008/12/very-simple-textbox-watermark-using-jquery/

I encourage to use a plugin, unless you have plenty of time developing and testing. There are many issues and side-effects to take notice of when writing this code.

- Validate the field as 'empty' when it contains the watermark text.
  Thus distinguish the watermark text from inputted text.
- Not submitting the watermark text.
- Prevent the user to type in the watermark text itself :)
- Styling the watermark text.
- etc, etc....

Comment: I just thought I'd let you know that 3 of the 4 links are broken.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the new HTML5 placeholder attribute.

**Edit**: update to use some more HTML5/jQuery hotness, HTML5 data storage.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="type here" data-placeholder-text="type here" />
```

This will work on all modern browsers. And gracefully degrade in IE. However for IE you'll have to use javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $input = $('#id_of_input_element');
    $input.focus(function() {
        if($(this).val() == $(this).data('placeholder-text')) { 
            $(this).val('') 
        }
    }).blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val($(this).data('placeholder-text'));
        }
    }).trigger('blur');
}):
```

Comment: @The_Butcher: thanks, I'm glad we're all hear helping each other out, but we should really be shinning the light on today, not living in the with all these javascript hacks.

Comment: ye, unfortunately many corporates and businesses cannot move from Win XP thus from ie6, as most of their software is made to work on ie6 :/

Comment: I understand that. But my solution not only gracefully degrades in all browsers, it requires not plugins, and it 100% future compatible. Code for the future is all I ask :)

Comment: A virtual -1 for The_Butcher for not *actually* upvoting the HTML5 answer. (As far as I can tell.) It has no upvotes as of my reading, but I'm about to give it one.

Comment: good solution, wasn't even aware of the new attribute! is there any reason not to use $(this).attr('placeholder') and avoid the repetition? IIRC, even the bad browsers can access unexpected attributes.

Comment: The reason I used the data API (which is the same as doing .attr('data-placeholder-text')) is so that you wouldn't have to actually type the place holder text in your javascript. This is good because presentation (html, css) should be separate from behavior (javascript)

Answer (score 4):

The functionality is known as watermark , and can be acheived in many ways, one of them is

```
onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter Email')this.value=''"
onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Enter Email'"
```

This will work for email textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [solution](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/default_text_fields_using_simple_jquery_trick.aspx).

```
$(".defaultText").focus(function(srcc)
{
    if ($(this).val() == $(this)[0].title)
    {
        $(this).removeClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val("");
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur(function()
{
    if ($(this).val() == "")
    {
        $(this).addClass("defaultTextActive");
        $(this).val($(this)[0].title);
    }
});

$(".defaultText").blur();
```

Comment: use [jquery.watermark](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Watermark) plugin as was suggested.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to future proof and use the data attributes? This way the code is future compatible, will validate as HTML5, and makes semantic sense.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this: using the title attribute to store the default text

```
$(function(){ 

$(".makedefault").bind("blur",function(){

if($(this).val().length == 0)
{
   $(this).val($(this).attr('title'));
}
});
$(".makedefault").bind("focus",function(){

if($(this).val() == $(this).attr('title'))
{
   $(this).val("");
}
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin (I'm an co-author)

https://github.com/tanin47/jquery.default_text

It clones an input field and put it there.

It works on IE, Firefox, Chrome and even iPhone Safari, which has the famous focus problem.

This way you do not have to be worried about clearing input field before submitting.

OR

If you want to HTML5 only, you can just use attribute "placeholder" on input field

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my approach (with jQuery):**

```
<input id="myBox" type="text" />

<script>
  // Input field and default text
  var $element = $('#myBox');
  var defaultText = 'Hello World';

  $element.focus(function(){
    // Focused
    $element.removeClass('defocused').addClass('focused');
    if($element.val() == defaultText)
      $element.val('');
  }).blur(function(){
    // Defocused
    $element.removeClass('focused').addClass('defocused');
    if($element.val() == '')
      $element.val(defaultText);
  });

  // Initialization
  $element.blur();
</script>
```